# SQL + IN + Parameter

Tags: sql, parameters

I have a string that I am passing as a parameter to my stored proc.

```
dim AgentString as String = " 'test1', 'test2', 'test3' "
```

I would like to use that parameter in the `IN` statement.

```
AND M.SalesRep IN (@AgentString)
```

However, this does not seem to work. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: SqlServer? MySql? Oracle? etc.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can do a string comparison.

```
dim AgentString as String = "test1,test2,test3"
```

And then have:

```
where ','+AgentString+',' like '%,'+M.SalesRep+',%'
```

I've put commas before and after everything, so "ed" does not match "edith".

Comment: One of the downsides is that it will also render useless any existing index on `SalesRep`, thus degrading performance.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `agentString` is being interpreted as a *single* string, instead of a list of values. If the number of parameters is fixed, you can use:

```
AND M.SalesRep IN (@agent0,@agent1,@agent2)
```

And then bind each parameter separately.

If not, you need to dynamically build your query to get to the above form, and then bind each argument in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The number of parameters is not fixed. (MS SQL 2008)

Comment: @user1422570: Ok, then you need to build your query dynamically in VB.NET. 1) Split the string into an array, `AgentString.Split(',')`; 2) For each element in the resulting array, add ":parmX," to your query; 3) Build the query; 4) For each parameter, normally bind its value to the previously created `parmX` named parameter, where `X` is the parameter position in the array.

Comment: sounds like a good plan for the vb.net part, however, how do I make the parameters dynamic on the SQL end?